# Redmine on Cygwin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cygwin, redmine

I need to install Redmine on my Windows 7 based workstation machine. I've aproached this a couple of times but there was always some failure regarding SQLITE 3 (or other stuff).

I gave up and downloaded a BITNAMI Redmine installation pack, but it has slowed down my workstation to the unreasonable level (redmine.exe consumed too much, even if I didn't do anything). I had to uninstall it.

Therefore, my question is: are there some instructions of how to install a lightweight version of Redmine on Cygwin, on Windows 7 based workstation? Have anyone done this? No MySQL, just SQLITE. No APACHE, just Mongrel or something even more lightweight.

Comment: Alternative servers are good in case of ultra-high traffic, caching/proxying architectures and large number of sites. Otherwise Apache is the way to go. Mongrel2 will be a fragile PITA, going by its getting started http://mongrel2.org/wiki/quick_start.html

Comment: so you're planning on using a remote database to hold redmine data?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but I don't like the choice of SQLITE either.  We had a redmine in SQLITE and found that we couldn't export its data to other databases.  So if your project is going to grow, it might make sense to just start with a "heavyweight" database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a virtual machine.

Comment: This is not the answer to my question, but I've followed your advice and installed Bitnami Redmine on my XP Mode. It works just fine (beside the fact that I have to run the XP Mode application, which is fairly slow).

Answer (score 1):

Why under cygwin? You can install Redmine under windows directly with no pack/bundle (I've just do it yesterday).
I've only installed ruby and mysql and theses consume:

- ruby.exe 0% cpu / 85Mb RAM
- montgrel_service.exe 0% cpu / 1.5Mb RAM
- mysqld.exe 0% cpu / 30Mb RAM

(0% cpu when no user use redmine, else no more than 5%).

So, what the deal with Cygwin? Which will recode all linux to windows functions and so consume real more cpu than a native windows software.

Comment: ruby.exe 0% cpu? What system do you have?

Comment: Windows XP, and I've used RubyInstaller.exe from ruby-lang.org. And I said that 0% is when there is no user currently using Redmine else it's taken no more than 5% (but where are only 3 to use it).

Comment: As I said before - on XP everything works fine with RubyInstaller. It is the Windows 7 that is making so much trouble :)